Converting keras_facenet model to tflite
How to convert keras_facenet model to tensorflow lite for face detection task. Model is pre trained just need to convert it
Repo link- https://github.com/Kartikgc9/faceRecognition_Labs/tree/master
I have tried searching for this everywhere but facing issues in finding .H5 file. Repo link is provided above
